# Unable to marshal response: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 48: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use this code on AWS Lambda, and it's showing this error: `Unable to marshal response: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 48: invalid continuation byte`, i tried to change isBase64Encoded between True and False but error still happening, have no idea.

```
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    video_data = requests.get("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4", stream=True)
    video_content = video_data.content
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
            "Content-Length": len(video_content)
        },
        "body": video_content,
        "isBase64Encoded": False
    }
    return response
```

Full Error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 48: invalid continuation byte",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 40419a51-2e14-4035-81f5-7f135131a2ac Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 48: invalid continuation byte
Traceback (most recent call last):END RequestId: 40419a51-2e14-4035-81f5-7f135131a2ac
REPORT RequestId: 40419a51-2e14-4035-81f5-7f135131a2ac  Duration: 1654.01 ms    Billed Duration: 1655 ms    Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 373 MB Init Duration: 240.18 ms

Request ID
40419a51-2e14-4035-81f5-7f135131a2ac
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete error message? Esp. which line is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

maybe that is because you have to encode the video

```
import base64
encoded_video_content = base64.b64encode(video_content).decode()
```

Then in the response  change it the following

```
  response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
    },
    "body": encoded_video_content,
    "isBase64Encoded": True
}
```